# R: setting options within an environment

Tags: r

Is there a way to set `options` within an environment? Something like

```
tmp_env = new.env()
within(tmp_env, options(mc.core = 16))
with(tmp_env, {
  # run parallel code here
})
```

I want to switch between using `options(mc.core = 16)` and `options(mc.core = 1)` explicitly and don't want to accidentally set off a parallelized computation.

Comment: I don't understand how environments are related to your question. Anyway, according to documentation `options` sets *global* options. The examples there show how to reset options which is a good habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a function or other closure (e.g., `local()`) to set the option, and use `on.exit()` to guarantee restoration on exit

```
fun = function() {
    old.opt = options(mc.cores=12)
    on.exit(options(old.opt))
    ## do work
}
```

You could get fancy with something like (based on `with.default`)

```
withp = function(expr, cores=4) {
    old.opt = options(mc.cores=cores)
    on.exit(options(old.opt))
    eval(substitute(expr), enclos=parent.frame())
}
```

and use

```
withp({
    message("hello")
    res <- mclapply(1:20, function(i) Sys.getpid())
    table(unlist(res))
}, cores=3)
```